# Como hacer que mi calculadora diga operacion no valida

Tags: java

He hecho una calculadora en java, todo funciona correctamente me pide un numero luego otro y si pongo suma, resta o multiplicacion etc me hace la cuenta.
pero si le pongo dos vacios cuando me pida un numero me da error os dejo el codigo

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Teclea dos números con o sin decimales");
    float numero1 = Float.parseFloat(sc.nextLine());
    float numero2 = Float.parseFloat(sc.nextLine());
    int op;
    op = 7;
    System.out.println("Introduce una operacion: suma, resta, multiplicacion, division o resto ");
    String operacion = sc.nextLine();
    float suma = numero1 + numero2;
    float resta = numero1 - numero2;
    float multiplicacion = numero1 * numero2;
    float division=numero1/numero2;
    float resto=numero1%numero2;    
    switch (operacion) {
        case "suma":
            System.out.println(suma);
            break;
        case "resta":
            System.out.println(resta);
            break;
        case "multiplicacion":
            System.out.println(multiplicacion);
            break;
        case "division":
            System.out.println(division);
            break;
        case "resto":
            System.out.println(resto);
            break;
         default:
       System.out.println("Operacion no valida" );
       break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Una de las cosas que podrias mejorar es la comprobación de los numeros cuando se piden,Si pones un 0 por ejemplo a la hora de la suma o resto no dara problemas pero y en la division? Te aconsejo poner la operacion elegida (por ej float suma = numero1 + numero2) dentro del switch  no antes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bienvenido al mundo de las excepciones:

Lo que está pasando es que en la linea `numero1=Float.parseFloat(sc.nextLine());` y en la linea `numero2=Float.parseFloat(sc.nextLine());` estas dando a entender que el usuario te va a meter siempre un número válido, lo cual no es así, ya que, como has visto, puedes no meterle nada, o meterle una letra (puedes probar, te dará el mismo error).

Lo que tienes que hacer es encapsular esas lineas que pueden lanzar excepciones en un `try catch`.

A continuación te explico cómo funciona un `try`y un `catch`:

> try:
>
> Todo código que encapsules en este bloque está sometido a una prueba, es decir, estás intentando ejecutarlo sin errores, pero en el caso que de que se produzca un error se deja de ejecutar automáticamente y pasa por el `catch`.

En nuestro ejemplo, si se produce un error en las lineas que te he mencionado, no se va a ejecutar `numeroNoValido=false;`

> cactch:
>
> Conocido como bloque de cometido capturador de los errores provocados en el `try`. Cada vez que se produce un error en un `try` y el error sea del tipo de excepción que estás "cogiendo" (catch en inglés), se va a ejecutar el código que esté dentro de este bloque.

En nuestro ejemplo, si se produce una excepcion de `NumberFormatException` lo cogemos en el `catch` con la declaración: `catch(NumberFormatException e)` pero... **si se produce cualquier otro tipo de error no va a entrar por el catch, si no que la aplicación te va a dar un error.**. Para evitar esto (si te interesa evitarlo, ya que no siempre interesa capturar absolutamente todos los errores) podrías hacer un `catch(Exception e)`. Es decir, que se produzca la excepción que se produzca, va a ejecutar lo que hay dentro del `catch`. Esta opción puede parecer una buena práctica, pero no lo es en absoluto.
La buena práctica es hacer varios `catch` para cada tipo de error y que ejecute diferentes cosas según el error.

Te dejo el código para solucionar tu problema. Pero no es la mejor solución, ya que, si el usuario mete mal el segundo número, le va a volver a pedir los dos números de nuevo. Esto se puede arreglar declarando Excepciones personalizadas tipo (`NumeroUnoNoValidoExcepction` y `NumeroDosNoValidoException`) y hacer diferentes catch para esas excepciones. No te voy a dar esa solución, ya que creo que es mejor que lo investigues por tu cuenta para que así aprendas mejor. Yo ya lo tengo implementado, si por lo que sea no consigues ésta otra solución que te propongo, te subo el código para que lo consigas.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean numeroNoValido=true;
        float numero1=0;
        float numero2=0;
        while(numeroNoValido){
             System.out.println("Teclea dos números con o sin decimales");
             try{
                 numero1=Float.parseFloat(sc.nextLine());
                 numero2=Float.parseFloat(sc.nextLine());
                 numeroNoValido=false;
             }
             catch(NumberFormatException e){
                 System.out.println("Número no válido o vacío");
                 numeroNoValido=true;
             }
            
        }
        
        int op;
        op = 7;
        System.out.println("Introduce una operacion: suma, resta, multiplicacion, division o resto ");
        String operacion = sc.nextLine();
        float suma = numero1 + numero2;
        float resta = numero1 - numero2;
        float multiplicacion = numero1 * numero2;
        float division=numero1/numero2;
        float resto=numero1%numero2;    
        switch (operacion) {
            case "suma":
                System.out.println(suma);
                break;
            case "resta":
                System.out.println(resta);
                break;
            case "multiplicacion":
                System.out.println(multiplicacion);
                break;
            case "division":
                System.out.println(division);
                break;
            case "resto":
                System.out.println(resto);
                break;
             default:
           System.out.println("Operacion no valida" );
           break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, soy un novato en este mundo voy a probar e investigar. 
PD: Eres un crack